# Executing a string command - Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

I have the following command line:

```
egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb\n", ips, nn}'
```

And that's producing a command line which I will use in my chef cookbook to start a `MapR` cluster:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C 10.32.237.251 -Z 10.32.237.251 -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb
```

My first command only prints out that command. How can I modify that command, or add anything else, to automatically execute the command produced by the `awk`?

Comment: Does `eval` do what you want?

Comment: As an aside, anything resembling `grep foo | awk '{ bar }'` can usually fruitfully be refactored to `awk '/foo/ { bar }'`.  See also [useless use of `grep | awk`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe it to the shell:

```
egrep '^[0-9]' /etc/hosts | grep -v 127.0.0.1 \
    | awk 'NR==1{ips=$1} 
            NR>1{ips=ips ", " $1} 
            $2=="namenode"{nn=$1} 
            END{ printf "/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -C %s -Z %s -N mycluster --create-user -D /dev/xvdb\n", ips, nn}' \
    | bash
```